# ADFS RelayState issue

Tags: adfs

I am using PingFederate for SP-initiated SSO and ADFS 3.0 for user authentication. It displays a login page where user enters credentials. This is failing only if the login page is idle for 10 or more minutes and then when users clicks on sign-in, the below error message shows up. If the login is before 10 minutes, there are no issues. I have noticed that the login page url has a RelayState guid. During successful authentication, it creates MSISContext cookie along with RelayState guide attached to it. When it errors out, from what I have read online, the response comes back to ADFS, ADFS checks for a cookie with the new RelayState name that doesn't exist. What can I do to fix this issue when the login page is idle for 10 or more minutes. Is there a timeout value that I can change somewhere?

Encountered error during federation passive request.

Additional Data

Protocol Name: 
Saml

Relying Party:

Exception details: 
Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.CookieManagers.InvalidContextException: MSIS7001: The passive protocol context was not found or not valid. If the context was stored in cookies, the cookies that were presented by the client were not valid. Ensure that the client browser is configured to accept cookies from this website and retry this request.
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.Saml.SamlProtocolHandler.GetOriginalRequestFromResponse(ProtocolContext context, Boolean deleteCookie)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.PassiveProtocolListener.ProcessProtocolRequest(ProtocolContext protocolContext, PassiveProtocolHandler protocolHandler)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.PassiveProtocolListener.OnGetContext(WrappedHttpListenerContext context)

Answer (score 3):

RelayState gets added to the name of the cookie. If the relay state changes, the response will check for a cookie with the new RelayState name that does not exist. Make sure that it [has not changed](https://nzpcmad.blogspot.com/2017/12/adfs-invalidcontextexception-msis7001.html) and ensure that you enabled [RelayState](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn486787.aspx) on your ADFS.

There are different service properties you may also need to include depending on your Windows Server version. See the threads below:

AD FS in Windows Server 2012 R2, for instance, includes a `%systemroot%\ADFS\Microsoft.IdentityServer.Servicehost.exe.config` file. If that is what you are using, create an element with the same syntax as the web.config file element: `<useRelayStateForIdpInitiatedSignOn enabled="true" />`. Include this element as part of `<microsoft.identityserver.web>` section of the Microsoft.IdentityServer.Servicehost.exe.config file.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/Lync/en-US/8d692a29-92e0-47e0-be70-d7f9335ab95a/adfs-30-relay-state-issue?forum=winserverDS

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/25239ff7-a33d-4f3e-a7a8-5a3c47d733f7/relaystate-support-in-adfs-30?forum=Geneva

https://nzpcmad.blogspot.com/2016/01/this-post-follows-on-from-idp-initiated.html